# How to combine two dictionaries in a single plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two dictionaries - one with the count of the key and the other with the average value of the key which look like this:

```
count_dict = {And:'4',But:'5',Cat:'20'}
average_dict = {And:'-0.5',But:'0.1',Cat:'0.2'}
```

And I would like to combine them into a scatter plot which looks like [this](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gsuitedevs/solutions@master/feedback-sentiment-analysis/summaryimage.png)

My actual dictionary is a lot bigger so it would be great if I could display only top X values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sure [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and its [scatter plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) will help you with your problem.